# send command to Slave and receive response over I2c

Tags: arduino-mega, i2c, attiny

so I have an Arduino mega as the master and an attiny84 as the slave
the master can send a command `S` to the slave and the slave should respond with `TRUE` so here is my code:

master:

```
bool GetOnline(){
      Serial.println("Sending Status Command ");
      
      if(Address != NULL){
        String res;
        Wire.beginTransmission(Address);
        Wire.write('S');
        Wire.endTransmission();
        Wire.requestFrom(Address, 4);
        while (Wire.available())
        {
          char inChr = Wire.read();
          res += inChr;
        }
        
        Serial.print("Device responce: ");
        Serial.println(res);
        if(res == "TRUE"){
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

Slave:

```
void normalReceive(uint8_t howMany) {
  while(Wire.available())//if wire is avaliable
  {
    char command=Wire.read();//state read the recived command from master, high or low
    MySerial.print("recived: "); MySerial.println(command);
    switch(command){
      case 'A': digitalWrite(LEDReboot,LOW);
       break;
      case 'B': digitalWrite(LEDReboot,HIGH);
       break;
      case 'S': Wire.write("TRUE"); 
       break;
      case 'R': resetFunc();  
       break;
      default: MySerial.print("recived: "); MySerial.println(command);
       break;
    }
  }
}

void normalRequest() { 
  MySerial.println("Request SN");
  Wire.write(sn); 
  }
```

now the issue is when I request from the slave it returns the SN rather than the expected `TRUE`

I am very new to I2C so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you really using the `Wire` library on the Attiny84? That chips doesn't have dedicated I2C hardware, so I thought that the `Wire` library doesn't work with it.

Comment: @chrisl well `TinyWireS` didn't work with `AttinyCore` and in the examples, from `AttinyCore` they used `Wire`

Comment: Ah, it seems, that the `Wire` library as provided by the ATtinyCore incorporates the other libraries and chooses automatically based on the given hardware.

Comment: What is `sn` in the function `normalRequest`? I can't see it being declared anywhere in the code. Does the Attiny84 recieve the `S`, can you see it in the Serial Monitor?

Comment: @PythonSchlange `sn` is a char array. the serial number of the Attiny84 device and yes the Attiny84 does receive the `S` Command

Comment: If I understand correctly you're saying that you're getting a value returned over I2C that only the function `normalRequest()` can return, without ever calling `normalRequest()`?